# How to add Cordova barcodescanner plugin sencha touch2.3

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch-2.2

I am initializing cordova in my app which was using touch2.3 and added barcodescanner.js file in app.json and build it successfully using sencha app build native.I loaded .apk file in my android and trying to run,when I hit scanner button it is raising an alert saying cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner not found.I updated config.xml . How to add custom cordova plugins to new Sencha tocuh2.3?.Please help me on where I was going wrong.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the repo using GIT or just a ZIP from Github.

Add the plugin to your project (from the root of your project):

go to your cordova or phonegap folder run follwing cmd

cordova plugin add

then run beloows for check

cordova plugin ls

Comment: Thank you so much... U really saved my time. I was trying to add it from sencha app and it is not working,now I moved to phonegap folder and then added plugin.. it works great :)

Comment: Yeah sure.. first step generate sencha app,2nd go to the app folder and initialize cordova in it, then you can see cordova folder in app folder and then download or add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner barcodescanner plugin in the cordova folder .. Ext.device.Scanner.scan({
      success: function(result) {  function to the scanner button. you  should do sencha app refresh before building it

Answer (score 0):

I tried following these instructions without success and let me be more specific:

1. created sencha 2.3 app called myscan
2. added Cordova (not Phonegap) with Sencha cordova init
3. cd to Cordova folder
4. added the plugin
    cordova  plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner
   5 build the app with sencha app build native

6 created a simple test
   Ext.device.Scanner.scan(function(c) {
                    alert("We got a barcode\nResult: " + c.text + "\nFormat: " + c.format +   "\nCancelled: " + c.cancelled)
                }, function(c) {
                    alert("Scanning failed: " + c)
                })

I was not surprised to see that Ext.device was not defined as all the example code I could find use the navigator object so I looked at the WildaBeast sample code and changed the call to
Cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan  ... Now everything is defined and I trace into the code and seems to make the call into IOS but nothing meaningful results and no callbacks are called.

Now Gigi are you using Sencha Cmd v4.0.1.45

Comment: Sencha Cmd v4.0.0.203 this is the current version I am using

Comment: so are u following the same steps that I outlined above and if not can u please show me the errors in my approach. Thank you.

Comment: U r trying on browser right?? did you added barcodescanner.js file reference in index.html???

Comment: this is cordova/sencha app so I point xcode at project that  results from the  sencha app build native command. this launches a cordova app  that runs on the iPhone5 as a "native app" . the point of Cordova is to produce a native (Objective C) wrapper that will do the barcode scan and return the resultant code to the JS.

Comment: actually the answer is adding these lines to config.xml     <feature name="BarcodeScanner">
<param name="ios-package"value="CDVBarcodeScanner" />
</feature>

Answer (score 0):

after installed barcode scanner plugin use sencha plugin [Ext.ux.mgd.device.Scanner](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-mgd-device-scanner)